# Why can I no longer use the PAGE-DOWN key in Firefox after upgrade on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, keyboard-navigation

I used to be able to navigate downward in web pages in Firefox on Windows 7.

I just installed Firefox 4 and can no longer do this.

I tried going back to version 3.6 but the problem has been carried back to that version too.

How can I restore the original functionality?

Comment: Works fine here, Firefox 4 / Windows 7.
Have you tried unplugging/replugging your keyboard ? Updating drivers ?

Comment: Drivers work fine. No problems with keyboard in other browsers or any other applications.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an addon has reserved that 'HotKey'. I recommend you start Firefox 4 with all addons disabled (i.e. Safe Mode) and see.

The key works fine on my FF4 + Win7x64